# Ramda get keys from nested object inside array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, nested-lists, ramda.js

I have an array of nested objects. I am trying to iterate though the array and get back a list of ids from the nested objects.

```
        "group": [
        {
          "groupId": "1",
          "subGroup": {
            "id": "44",
            "name": "Testing",
          }
        },
 {
          "groupId": "2",
          "subGroup": {
            "id": "45",
            "name": "Testing",
          }
        },
 {
          "groupId": "3",
          "subGroup": {
            "id": "46",
            "name": "Testing",
          }
        }
      ]
```

I am trying to return a list of ids like so => `[44, 45, 46]`

I tried `const result = map(path("subGroup", "id"), group),` but it did not produce the result I need.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you've taken is fine, except that [`R.path`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) expects an array of path indexes rather than multiple arguments.

```
map(path(["subGroup", "id"]), group)
```

Alternatively, you could also just use the `map` method of arrays to achieve the same result.

```
group.map(g => g.subGroup.id)
```